# Single Criteria INDEX MATCH with concatenated criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vba

I am having trouble with the following `Index/Match` formula in VBA.

Following is the code

```
Sub MSTitl_box()

Dim Target As Range
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Variant
Dim refdate As Variant
Dim discat As Variant
Dim Milestone As Variant
Dim criteria As Variant

Set Target = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Address)

x = Target.Column - 2    
y = Target.Row - 2

refdate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("C2:AF2"), x)    
discat = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B3:B23"), y)    
z = discat & refdate    
criteria = Formula = "=MATCH(" & z & ",msrng,0)"  
Milestone = Formula = "=INDEX(colm_mstitle_rng," & criteria & ",0)"

MsgBox criteria

End Sub
```

The variable `refdate` is a date value in format "m/d/yyyy" & `discat` is a text string.

The `z` is showing the right concatenated value for x & y. But when it goes to MATCH formula, it says FALSE and subsequently the index formula fails.

I think it has something to do with variable definition.

Comment: what is `msrng` in the `"MATCH"` formula ?

Comment: Its a named range column. where the value of z is being matched.

Comment: but where do you want to put your `Formula` ? what is `criteria = Formula =...` suppose to be ? I think you should try the VBA way, without using the `Formula`, try `criteria = Application.Match(Z, Range("msrng"), 0)`

Comment: I tried to use INDEX MATCH formula with multiple criteria. With Evaluate function, the formula worked but when i tried to use the same formula with some defined variables like refdate and discat, it will return type mismatch error at formula.

Comment: Then i change the approach to a single criteria index match formula with 2 criteria concatenated as a primary key. This primary key will be the lookup criteria for INDEX MATCH. Now the problem is , my defined variables i.e x, y, z, refdate and discat, they are working, i can see the correct values in local window as i move through this code. But when it comes to "criteria" which is actually the MATCH portion of INDEX MATCH, the result is False and that fails the INDEX formula in next step..

Comment: The excel formulas are working just fine. But i cant get them to work in VBA.

Comment: Array formula : =INDEX(colm_mstitle_rng,MATCH(1,(colm_dis_crt=AL27)*(colm_date1=AM26),0))      Current formula : =INDEX(colm_mstitle_rng,MATCH(CONCATENATE(AL27,AM26),DateTables!$I$5:$I$9,0))